# 32 bit vs 64 bit IDA Pro

Tags: ida, idapro-sdk

I am confused on the differences between using 64 bit and 32 bit IDA versions on a 32 bit application.

If I use 64 bit IDA on the 32 bit application, will it make use of 64 bit or 32 bit architecture?

Answer (score 2):

First, the IDA 32 will not load a 64 image, and the 64 will disassemble a 32 image, but the only difference is in the generated pseudocode, if you want to generate a pseudocode in C, you need to use the correct version of IDA, read:

- [Decompiler limitations](https://hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/limit.shtml)
  (this link will clarify the difference between the versions).

according to the Hex-Rays website:

> Limitations specific to x86:
>
> only 32-bit code can be analyzed with ida32

> Limitations specific to x64:
>
> only 64-bit code can be analyzed with ida64

a long time ago a user asked a similar question and received the answer from one of the developers:

> "IDA Pro 64" allowed you to analyze 64-bit files but it was itself a
> 32-bit program (until version 7.0)".

I recommend a quick read if you're just starting out:

- [Difference between a 32-bit and 64-bit](https://techterms.com/help/difference_between_32-bit_and_64-bit_systems)

Comment: Those limitations are on the decompiler not on IDA Pro itself. The decompiler is an optional plugin for IDA Pro.

Comment: excellent positioning indeed.